# Utilizando o synchronized do Java

Tags: java, programação-estruturada

Estava fazendo alguns exercícios em Java, e acabei me deparando com este código abaixo em uma questão, afirmando que "A implementação do método `doLog` da classe `Escritor` deve ser qualificado como `synchronized`".

Como faço para qualificar o método da forma que ele falou? E que tipo de modificação teria que fazer nele para utilizar o `synchronized` do Java?.

```
public class Escritor extends Thread {

    private BufferedReader input;
    protected PrintStream out;

    Escritor(Socket sock, PrintStream arq) throws IOException {
        input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(sock.getInputStream()));
        out = arq;
    }

    public void run() {
        String line;
        try {
            while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
                doLog(line);
            }
            input.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
        }
    }

    private void doLog(String text) throws IOException {
        Date date = new Date();
        out.print(date + ":");
        out.println(text);
    }
}

public class Server {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws FileNotFoundException {
        Escritor task;
        PrintStream out = new PrintStream(new File("log.txt"));
        try {

            ServerSocket sock = new ServerSocket(8888);
            while (true) {
                Socket con = sock.accept();
                task = new Escritor(con, out);
                task.start();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println(e);
        }
        out.close();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basta colocar na assinatura do método `doLog` a palavra chave `synchronized`, dessa forma:

```
private synchronized void doLog(String text) {
    //seu código sincronizado;
}
```

Para mais informações sobre o funcionamento dos métodos sincronizados sugiro que veja a [documentação](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/syncmeth.html).

Comment: Blz Gustavo, obrigado vlw pela dica.